# Get icon name for a stock ID?

Tags: gtk

#### Question

I'm trying to retrieve the (string) icon name(s) corresponding to a given (string) Gtk stock ID.

#### Example

Gtk stock id 'gtk-go-forward' has *two* corresponding icon names, 'gtk-go-forward-ltr' and 'gtk-go-forward-rtl'. I'd like to retrieve either:

- both icon names 'gtk-go-forward-ltr' and 'gtk-go-forward-rtl' given the ID 'gtk-go-forward'; **OR**
- just the icon name 'gtk-go-forward-ltr' (the "appropriate" one for my text direction).

#### Potential restrictions

I'm using the gobject introspection API, not the base C one.

#### Rationale (optional to read)

I'm trying to make a [`St.Icon`](http://developer.gnome.org/st/stable/StIcon.html) for the icon specified by the stock ID, but at a largish size (96 px).

I can use [`gtk_icon_set_render_icon`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/gtk-Themeable-Stock-Images.html#gtk-icon-set-render-icon) with the stock ID 'gtk-go-forward' directly like so (it picks the LTR version) (the syntax is GNOME javscript but this is irrelevant to the quesiton; I'm using the GObject introspection API):

```
let style = Gtk.Widget.get_default_style();
let iconset = style.lookup_icon_set('gtk-go-forward');
let icon = new St.Icon({
    gicon: iconset.render_icon(gtkStyle, Gtk.TextDirection.LTR,
                               Gtk.StateType.NORMAL, Gtk.IconSize.DIALOG,
                               null, null),
    icon_type: St.IconType.FULLCOLOR,
    icon_size: 96
});
```

This will give me an icon for stock ID 'gtk-go-forward' (it picks 'gtk-go-forward-ltr'), **but** the icon is very fuzzy.

**Alternatively** if I feed in the icon name 'gtk-go-forward-ltr' directly, the icon is *not* fuzzy:

```
let icon = new St.Icon({
    gicon: Gio.ThemedIcon.new_with_default_fallbacks('gtk-go-forward-ltr'),
    icon_type: St.IconType.FULLCOLOR,
    icon_size: 96
});
```

So in summary, I think that my best bet at getting a large, non-fuzzy icon is to find the icon name for the stock ID, rather than using the stock ID (feeding `gtk-go-forward` to the second method above produces the "missing icon" icon as it is not a valid icon name).

[image: Icon using stock ID (top); using icon name (bottom)]

In the picture above the top icon uses the first method (stock ID with render_icon) and the bottom icon uses the second method (use the icon name directly). Big difference in clarity.

Answer (score 8):

### General Stock Icon Names

This question is a little old now, but for future reference: it's best to use `"go-next"` rather than `"gtk-go-forward"` -- this is the correct name according to the [Icon Naming Spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html#names), and recommended since GTK developers are planning on [deprecating stock icons shortly](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KCVPoYQBqMbDP11tHPpjW6uaEHrvLUmcDPqKAppCY8o/pub).

To directly answer the question as stated in the title: here is a [handy Google Docs spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AsPAM3pPwxagdGF4THNMMUpjUW5xMXZfdUNzMXhEa2c&output=html) giving the equivalent icon spec names for GTK stock icons.

### Non-fuzzy, large versions of GTK Icons

As to getting non-fuzzy versions of default icons, the best way I've found to render an icon at 96px in GTK is to load it into a `GdkPixbuf`, and then use that rather than a `GtkIcon` (which is limited to 48px, that being the largest `GtkIconSize`, as j__m pointed out). An example of how to do this in Vala (easily converted to JS or Python etc):

```
var icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default();
try {
    var pixbuf = icon_theme.load_icon("go-next", 96, Gtk.IconLookupFlags.USE_BUILTIN);
    // Do something with the pixbuf, for example use it with a CellRendererPixbuf,
    // or a GtkButton or whatever
catch (GLib.Error e) {
    GLib.critical("Could not load icon: %s", e.message);
}
```

You might also want to experiment with `Gtk.IconLookupFlags.FORCE_SIZE` and/or `FORCE_SVG`, particularly if you want really huge icons.

I'm afraid I've never use the Shell Toolkit, so I don't know whether you particularly need an `St.Icon`, but in plain GTK you can use a `GdkPixbuf` pretty much anywhere you can use a stock icon so this is a workaround I've found very useful.

Answer (score 1):

`GTK_ICON_SIZE_DIALOG` (`Gtk.IconSize.DIALOG` in Javascript) is smaller than 96px.  You're rendering a small icon and then blowing it up; naturally it's going to look bad.

As I recall, the value `-1` returns the icon in whatever its original size is.  Then you can use St.Icon to set the size you want to draw it at, since that seems to be how you want to use it anyway.